# How to use google.maps.Size

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

While instantiating an object of google.maps.Map class, I want to set the width and height of the map.

```
 var mapOptions = {                
                   center: new google.maps.LatLng(122.5, 200),                 
                   mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;
                   zoom: 15,                   
                   scaleControl: false,       
                };
                this.map.mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), mapOptions);
```

I'm using above code to create instance of Google map but I dont know how to use google.maps.Size class.

Could anyone please explain how to use google.maps.Size class ?

Comment: Have you looked into the Google Maps documentations for help?

Comment: I tried that but its showing google.maps.Size class to use but don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1):

There is no size property in the [MapOptions object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions). You have to make sure your HTML element ("google_map") has a valid size when the map is created or trigger the "resize" event on the map object once it has a valid size.

Comment: There is no option for size but there is google.maps.Size class for that, but don't know how to use it

Comment: You don't know how to use it where? In what context?  I was answering based on the information in your question. If that is not correct, please update your question to be clearer.

Comment: I want to know how to use google.maps.Size to set map width and height. Your answer is correct but, i have to set width and height at the time of map initialization.

Comment: You can't set the map width and height explicitly on the map object in v3 (or if you can, it isn't documented that I know of), it takes the size computed by the browser.